# How to fix mobile background white space

Tags: css

How do I get rid of the white space showing up in the background. It only happens once on the initial load. whenever you refresh it goes away. Any suggestions will be helpful. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
body {
        background-image: url("https://www.example.com");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Please put up a working snippet so we can try it for ourselves. Nothing obvious springs out from the CSS you have given (but be aware that background-attachment: fixed does not work as expected on IOS).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it last night by removing the background-attachment: fixed.